# Different applications with same controls but different Design

Tags: c#, wpf, architecture

I have multiple Applications that all do nearly the sam, the only difference beetwem are different Text and Icons/Buttonimages/Textcolors. The Layout is the same.

My Problem is know how I can build reusable Layouts/Controls that can be used by each Application and there use the right Color or Image.

At the moment i,ve got one roject for each Application, another Project that contains the mainwindow, with als models,viewmodels, models and so on. 
The Applicationproject know creates an Instance of the Mainwindow with parameters, like Applicationtype and applicationspecific resources. the mainwindow is know binding, each time it needs a "appspecific" value (i.e. image, color), by dynamicbinding to the resourcedictionary that comes from the application.

I think this is not a good solution, because I only see if the dynamicbinding is corrupt at runtime.

Is their s.th. like a best practice to solve this issue?

Comment: Please expose Color, Image etc. as dependency properties to your custom control and allow the application to set it

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise. As such, it is off topic for this website and therefore I have voted to close it. Perhaps you can re-word it to make it less subjective.